# error_reporting(0); in a function

Tags: php

I'm working with classes and functions trying to learn and I'm doing a fsockopen to check if a server is online or not. All is well when I do it straight from the page (not calling the function.) I'm trying to turn error reporting off just for a particular function.
EDIT: I've also tried adding error_reporting straight into the function, that did not work either.

```
class server
{

public function __construct() {
    global $servhost;
    global $gameport;
    global $loginport;
    $this->fp = fsockopen($servhost, $gameport, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    $this->er = error_reporting(0);

                              }

function servstatus()
{
    // tried this echo $this->er;
    // tried this $this->er;
    // tried this error_reporting(0);

    if ($this->fp) {

         echo "Server Online";

         fclose($this->fp);

        } else {

           echo "Server Offline";

           fclose($this->fp);

               }

                     }
}
```

Comment: Can the down voter explain how this post does not show research effort, is unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)** to suppress error reporting on function calls or expressions.

For example `$status = @servstatus();` or `$this->fp = @fsockopen($servhost, $gameport, $errno, $errstr, 5);`

I recommend you try to find a better way of handling the error or warning rather than just ignoring it though.  Suppression should only be used  in certain situations and can cause issues when debugging, so it should be used with caution.

Comment: What would be a better way? Can you point me in the right direction? I figured that the error would always show up as long as fsockopen couldn't connect?

Comment: What error are you receiving?  According to the manual, there should only be a warning if the hostname is incorrect.

Comment: It is just a warning, but @ does turn it off. The warning is 

`(No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)` But it does work if the server is online.

Comment: Might not be a way around it then, suppressing is probably fine in this case.  Just be careful using suppression, it can cause lots of problems when trying to debug.

Comment: Also, is there any reason why my echoing is not working? It does not display any text.